# Why are Java Timer threads disappearing?

Tags: java, multithreading, timertask

I have code that schedules one-time tasks to execute and does this over and over. It looks something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    while(true)
    {
    ....
    TimerTask closeTask = new CloseTask(cli);
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    timer.schedule(closeTask, (long) (iPeriod * 60 * 1000));
    ...
    }
}   
public class CloseTask extends TimerTask 
{
    Client client;
    CloseTask(Client in_client)
    {
        client = in_client;
    }
    public void run()
    {       
        try
        {           
            for(int iRetries = 0; state == OPEN; iRetries++)
            {                   
                logger.log_trade_line_grablock( "Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": About to send message", true, true, true, true, true);
                client.send_mesg("close");
                logger.log_trade_line_grablock( "Waiting 5 seconds before retrying ", true, true, true, true, true);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

The intent of the `run()` method in the `CloseTask` class is to loop until the `state` variable changes from `OPEN` state to something else. However, intermittently the timer threads simply disappear, while `state` still equals `OPEN`, which I know by printing out all the thread ID's of the currently running threads every 5 minutes.

So my questions:
1) The only explanation I can think of is that the `CloseTask` object is throwing uncaught exceptions. Is that correct?
2) If 1) is correct why isn't my try catch block catching these exceptions?
3) If 1) is correct is there a way to catch these exception that slip through uncaught?

Thanks for any insight into this issue.

Comment: Um, your `main` method just finishes after scheduling the task. Does your real code have more after that?

Comment: Whats `cli` within your `main` method that you use to instantiate your `closeTask` variable?

Comment: I suspect this is the relevant bit of the `Timer` documentation though: "After the last live reference to a Timer object goes away and all outstanding tasks have completed execution, the timer's task execution thread terminates gracefully (and becomes subject to garbage collection)." Basically, you need to keep a reference to the `Timer`

Comment: @Anthony Forloney Its third party code.

Comment: @Jon Yea sorry there's more obviously. I'll add something to suggest that.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a `Timer` instance, but not making sure that it doesn't get garbage collected.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html):

> After the last live reference to a Timer object goes away and all outstanding tasks have completed execution, the timer's task execution thread terminates gracefully (and becomes subject to garbage collection).

So basically, you need to hold on to the reference to the `Timer` you created instead of just using a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

The boolean you are passing in tells whether or not the thread created will be `daemon`.  If it is daemon, the thread will be stopped once all non-daemon threads are finished.  Since the only non-daemon thread being run in your application is the main thread then it will immediately be stopped after the main method is completed.

As Jon Skeet mentioned there is some completion operations done if no live thread is referencing the Timer and the tasks complete, but if it's daemon and the main method completes, it may not exit gracefully.  To continue the documentation

> ... However, this can take arbitrarily long to occur. By default, the task execution thread does not run as a daemon thread, so it is capable of keeping an application from terminating. If a caller wants to terminate a timer's task execution thread rapidly, the caller should invoke the timer's cancel method.

To answer your question

> The only explanation I can think of is that the CloseTask object is throwing uncaught exceptions. Is that correct?

If the JVM kills a non-daemon thread, it won't throw any exception.  So you won't really know that it happened.

Comment: One thing I should emphasize is that the timer threads shouldn't be dying at all because 'state' variable referenced in my run() method is still OPEN. That's why I'm wondering about uncaught exceptions? Anything to that?

Comment: @user2722568 I was *just* answering that question, sorry shouldve included it initially.  Basically, if the JVM is killing your thread because it is `daemon`, your thread or task will never throw an exception and report the error.  I would try to flip the flag from true to false, and you should see it execute correctl.y

Comment: @user2722568 Also keep in mind, declaring it non-daemon, you will have to ensure the TimerTask eventually completes or else it will keep your app running indefinitely.

Comment: Aha OK so it could all go back to that daemon bool flag. OK I'll try flipping it and will post the results. Thanks.

Comment: @user2722568 Did that end up solving your problem

Comment: Well not that specifically the problem I stated was not accurate, in fact. I did more research on what was actually going on. The threads were not disappearing but going into a WAIT state.